# How to get information when battery status sets full

Tags: android, battery, receiver

my question is... how to get information **when** battery status sets full.
I've tried do this by receiver on ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED, but this isn't working, I'm almost sure that receiver not even get this broadcast. Maybe i don't understand this properly, action_battery_changed means that is signalized when our battery get another % ? Or only in particular events like disconnected or connected, because this actions works in my application(in another class receiver).

```
<receiver android:name="com.lily.chargingscheduler.ChangingBatteryStatsOnReceiver"   >
      <intent-filter>
          <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED" />
      </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

And class :

```
 public class ChangingBatteryStatsOnReceiver  extends BroadcastReceiver {
    static BDHelper db_helper;
    private String data;
    String level_;
    String answer;

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    db_helper = new BDHelper(context);
    data = (new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm")).format(new Date());
    level_ = batteryLevel(context);

    if(db_helper.getLastRow().get_TO_D().equals("")){
        if(level_ == "100%"){// level return % as a String
            answer = calculate();//calculate returns date and other things
            ending_charging(context);//adding to table and notification of this event   
        }
    }
}
```

[edit]

Maybe i wasn't specific enough, i don't have problem with getting information about battery level, I've problem with getting information when my battery is full.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
             context.unregisterReceiver(this);
             int currentLevel = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_LEVEL, -1);
             int scale = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_SCALE, -1);
             int level = -1;
             if (currentLevel >= 0 && scale > 0) {
                 level = (currentLevel * 100) / scale; // level will returns 99 or 100 when battery is full
             }
             batteryPercent.setText("Battery Level Remaining: " + level + "%");
         }
     }; 
     IntentFilter batteryLevelFilter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED);
     registerReceiver(batteryLevelReceiver, batteryLevelFilter);
}
```

As additional, if you want to listen the battery on low status, add this `<intent-filter/>`:

```
<receiver android:name=".ChangingBatteryStatsOnReceiver">
<intent-filter>
  <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_BATTERY_LOW"/>
  <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_BATTERY_OKAY"/>
  </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Comment: Maybe i wasn't specific enough, i don't have problem with getting information about battery level, I've problem with getting information when my battery is full.  And i need to do  registerReceiver in class extended BroadcastReciever ? I though that is necessary when we created class receiver in activity class.

Comment: Read this site for more information about monitoring the battery: http://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/battery-monitoring.html

Comment: Yea, thanks i've gone through the text a several times before asking, but maybe I've missed something.